# Why doesn't Outlook properly open when scheduled to start using Task Scheduler?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, microsoft-outlook-2016, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have scheduled a task in Task Scheduler to start Outlook at a certain time in the very early morning hours so it can execute a macro on startup. My settings in Task Scheduler are as follows.

- In the **General** tab, I have chosen options **Run whether user is logged on or not** and **Run with highest privileges**
- Under **Actions** > Edit Action > Settings, I have **Program/script:** `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"` and **Add arguments (optional):**`/recycle`
- In the **Conditions** tab, everything is unchecked
- In the **Settings** tab, I have checked **Allow task to be run on demand** so I can do a manual run to simulate what will happen in the scheduled run

I also did an **Export the selected task to a file**, increased the task priority from the default 7 to 4, then imported the task back into Task Scheduler.

Now, when I do a test Run from the panel on the right, Outlook does start running in the background (as can be seen in Task Manager), but Outlook does not actually appear/open on the screen (the way it usually opens to let you read mail, interact, etc.). I would like Outlook to actually open up, not just run in the background. Can Task Scheduler even achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this issue occur to other applications when scheduled to start using task scheduler? Not familiar with task scheduler, but found this article(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/253942/fix-task-scheduler-task-only-runs-in-the-background-after-you-use-sysp) discussing a similar issue for your reference.

Comment: @YukiSun: Thanks, Yuki. This issue did not occur when I scheduled another application to run using Task Scheduler.